# copy json object to another with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying copy JSON Object to another with js.

example

```
{name:'edo', email:'edo@example.com'}
```

I'm looking to do this

```
{person: {name: 'edo', email:'edo@example.com'}}
```

Any suggested how to make it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information about `{name:'edo', email:'edo@example.com'}`? Is there a variable that's referring to that object? Also, is it an object? Or is it a string in JSON format? I'm asking bc a lot of questions seem to confuse these two.

Comment: Very odd question. I see he already made the wanted object in JSON format... and even ridiculous to accept Syntax Error answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
{}.person = {name:'edo', email:'edo@example.com'}
```

I don't quite understand your question, do you mean Object 'Clone'?

Comment: Thanks, It's exactly what I needed :)

Comment: This is funny for gotten accepted, because `{}.person` would be simply `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Object.create({}).person = {name:'edo', email:'edo@example.com'};

Comment: @Leo Sorry about the mistake, although I was just trying to express the idea. I guess he is confused about the concept of object clone, maybe that's the answer he needs.